# Apache POI "addPicture" method not working for me

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a problem with inserting a picture into an Excel Workbook with Apache POI(version 3.7). Here's my code:

```
private static void createAndFillWorkbook() {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        File picture = new File("D:\\pngPict.png");
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) picture.length()];
        in = new FileInputStream(picture);
        in.read(buf);
        workbook.addPicture(buf, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
        out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Book3.xls");
        workbook.write(out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

It's not working(I'm using the .xls file format) and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main issue is Apache poi `addPicture` api depends on apache common codec.Download the jar `commons-codec-1.6` from this location http://commons.apache.org/codec/download_codec.cgi  and place the jar in your class path.

It should work . Also try sample examples of adding Pictures to an Excel

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Images

There is also a sample working code here

http://www.codemiles.com/java/image-insert-in-excel-file-using-poi-t1340.html

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thank you! I'm try it later and answer you about results.

Comment: I have the same problem... As you said , I tried adding the jar . But still I am unable to add the picture.Neither I am getting any exceptions. What might be the actual problem??

Comment: @Stunner Add the jar in your build path ..and then try to use it. :) Sorry for the delayed reply